# using Map for an object api

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

i have an object format api like this:

```
{ success: 1,
  result:[
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {} ]
}
```

how can i named a map on result parameter of this object? :/

i try 2 ways for it:
1- define api to a variable like x: `const [x, setX] = useState([])`;
then define result of api to another varibale like: `const y = x.result`;
and then make a map on Y .

2- define api to a variable like x: `const [x, setX] = useState([])`;
then make it array with this method: `const y = Object.entries(x)`;
and get "result" of this array like this:
`const result = y[1]`;
and make a map on result .

but after every 2 ways i see this error in console: :(

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Can you show your code, where you "make a map on result"? If you've get error there, it is better to see the code

Comment: hello, im working on reactJS. steps of my levels are: 1-get api data with a function 2-create context and define that function to it (and inerate object api in this context and export array of this api) 3-create a component and import that context in it and create map of variable "result" in this component! and see error :)

Comment: **this is cotext code**   `export const PlayerContext = createContext();

const PlayerContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState({});
    const result = players.result;

    useEffect(async () => {
        const fetchAPI = setPlayers(await getPlayers());

        return fetchAPI;
    }, [])

    return (
        <PlayerContext.Provider value={result}>
            {children}
        </PlayerContext.Provider>
    );
};`

Comment: **and its component code:** `import React, { useContext } from 'react';

//context
import { PlayerContext } from '../context/PlayerContextProvider';

//component
import Player from './Player';

const Players = () => {

    const result = useContext(PlayerContext);
    console.log(result);

    return (
        <div>
            {result.map(player => <Player key={player.player_key} data={player} />)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Players;`

Answer (score 0):

I found that you use useEffect a little bit incorrectly. You don't need return result in useEffect function. Instead it should be passed to `setState` function as argument:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const players = await getPlayers();
    setPlayers(players);
  }, []);
```

as your player data fetch operation is asynchronous, you can use conditional rendering in component:

```
{result ? result.map(player => <Player key={player.player_key} data={player} />) : loading...}
```

to sure that `result`  won't be `undefined` at moment of component mounting.

Comment: one another question pls -_- how can i access to sub arrays while "result" is undefined?!! **for example** `{ success: 1,
  result:[
     {s.th: [
 {},
 {}
      ] },
     {},
     {},
     {} ]
}` . how can i access to s.th array of object?!

Comment: you should use index of array for access: `result[0]` will give you access for first element in array

Comment: i do that, but beacause the result need a break to getting, itself is undefined in first moment mounting and result[x] isnt exist -_-

Comment: As I already have mensioned above, use conditional rendering or initial value for useState hook to resolve issue of undefined value. Check that value exist at moment of component initialization.